# Pass a list through pgfkey

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

I'm declaring a new shape [which looks like an Integrated Circuit].
One of the options I want to provide for this shape should be a list of positive integers with arbitrary length [which configures something about the IC ports]. For example, the call to create a node of this shape should look like:

```
\node (X) [TheShape,LeftPorts={2,4,3}] {};
```

... or at least that's what I hope to have. The above won't work because the commas will be interpreted as beginning of a new `<key>=<value>` pair.

I will later want to iterate though this `LeftPorts` list with `\foreach` multiple times to perform maths (such as sum) and drawing. Hence, the next obvious alternative:

```
\node (X) [TheShape,LeftPorts/.list={2,4,3}] {};
```

does not seem to work(?). Since it will be processing through the list with `.code` in just a single run; and without any place for me to setup initial condition for the loop. (like resetting sum counter to 0)

**The question is:** How to pass such list of integer through pgfkeys so it can be later processed by `\foreach` freely multiple times.

---

To give some code to work on and show another attempt by using `\noexpand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    Total/.initial=2,
    List/.initial=2,
    LeftPorts/.initial=2,
    LeftPorts/.code={
        \tikzset{List=#1}
        % calculate total
        \foreach \x in #1 { % <- not working.
            \tikzset{Total=\x}
        }
    },
}

\newcommand{\listVals}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item LeftPorts: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/LeftPorts}
        \item List: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/List}
        \item Total: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Total}
    \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{LeftPorts=\noexpand{4,5,6}}
    \listVals
\end{document}
```

expected result:

- LeftPorts: 2
- List: 4,5,6
- Total: 6

Actual result:

- LeftPorts: 2
- List: 4,5,6
- Total: 2

Note: If you can show how to use that `\foreach` to do total sum or product as well, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**: a new version with some factorizations...

Your initial syntax is good. Don't forget: a `foreach` is a group, so new definitions of macros are local to this group.

May be that the following example may help you (the trick is `\xdef\macro{\macro}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    List/.initial={2},
    UseList/.code n args={3}{% macro, init, operator
      \edef\mylist{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/List}}
      \gdef#1{#2} % set initial value
      \foreach \x in \mylist {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro#1{#1#3\x}
        \xdef#1{#1} % global definition
      }
    },
    Sum/.style={UseList={#1}{0}{+}},
    Product/.style={UseList={#1}{1}{*}},
}
\newcommand\showList{List: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/List}}
\begin{document}
% default list
\showList\par
\typeout{a}
\tikzset{Sum=\sum,Product=\product}
Sum: \sum{}  Product: \product{}\par
% set a new list
\tikzset{List={1,2,4}}
\showList\par
\tikzset{Sum=\sum,Product=\product}
Sum: \sum{}  Product: \product{}\par
% append new values
\tikzset{List/.append={,3,5}}
\showList\par
\tikzset{Sum=\sum,Product=\product}
Sum: \sum{}  Product: \product{}\par
\end{document}
```

Its result:

```
List: 2
Sum: 2 Product: 2
List: 1,2,4
Sum: 7 Product: 8
List: 1,2,4,3,5
Sum: 15 Product: 120
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning so many useful things here: `\typeout` for example. One more thing, it seems I need to learn properly about group. Can you recommend a resource?

Comment: @Billiska "The TeXbook"... or "TeX for the Impatient" (p.68).